# Advantages of actors over futures

Tags: actor, future

I currently program in Futures, and I'm rather curious about actors. I'd like to hear from an experienced voice:

- What are the advantages of actors over futures?
- When should I use one instead of other?

As far as I've read, actors hold state and futures doesn't, is this the only difference? So if I have true immutability I shouldn't care about actors?

Please enlighten me :-)

Comment: Java or Scala, but I guess this question would be rather language-agnostic; am I wrong?

Comment: Well, only a very select number of languages have both, most only do one or the other, if at all, and the quality of the implementations varies wildly. I don't think there's a meaningful agnostic response to this.

Comment: Let's say scala actors and java futures, can you provide me some information on the trade-offs?

Comment: I found this post to be very mind clearing when it comes to the relationship between actors and futures (in Scala): http://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One important difference is that actors typically have internal state, and therefore theoretically, they are not composable; see [this](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/04/erlang-style-actors-are-all-about.html) and [this](http://pchiusano.blogspot.com/2010/01/actors-are-not-good-concurrency-model.html) blog post for having some issues elaborated. However, in practice, they usually provide a sweet spot between the imperative and the purely functional approach. So if possible, it is recommended to stick to programming with only futures, but if the message-passing model fits your problem domain better, feel free to use actors.

Comment: You might also want to look into iteratees: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/scalaz-tutorial-enumeration-based-io-with-iteratees/

Comment: The promises link is highly out of date by the way, as of 2014.